# VBA click "open" on dialog prompt box, after downloading file

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I want to download a file via an URL, using VBA. How can I click on "save as" or "open", without using the "sendkeys" command?

This is my code so far:

```
Sub Orders_downloaden()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object

    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    'IE.Visible = False

    ie.navigate "http://k2b-bulk.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SMDownloadPickup"

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    Do While ie.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    ie.Visible = True

    Set link = ie.Document.getelementsbytagname("a")
    For Each l In link
    If l.innertext = "Download" Then
        l.Click
        Dim Report As Variant

        Report = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("Orders.csv", "Excel Files (*.csv), *.csv")
        'Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe -url " & l), vbHide
        Exit For
    End If
    Next l

End Sub
```

Does someone have any idea how to manage this?

Comment: which part of your code does not work as expected?

Comment: @YowE3K the question indeed looks quite the same as mine.

Comment: @jsotola I would like to click on "open" in the dialog box, without using "sendkeys" because I want to run the program in the background.